# elasticsearch.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')

Tags: python, elasticsearch

My code is crashing when I execute the following code, I must say I have already documents indexed in ES

```
db = ElasticVectorSearch(
    elasticsearch_url=url,  # it is fine, I didnt change it
    index_name=os.environ["ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_NAME"],
    embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"],
                         deployment=os.environ["AZURE_OPENAI_EMBEDDINGS_DEPLOYMENT"]),
    ssl_verify={"ca_certs": os.environ["APP_LANGCHAIN_CERT_PATH"]})

docs = db.similarity_search(query="my query", 
                            k=10)
```

Thank you

It was working before, I removed the indexes and I created them with

```
client.options(ignore_status=400).indices.create(index=os.environ["ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX"])
```

Comment: What Python library are you using? And which version of ES?

Comment: It was working before, I removed the indexes and I created them with `client.options(ignore_status=400).indices.create(index=os.environ["ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX"])`

Comment: ok, and what about my two questions?

Comment: Sorry, ES: 8.8.2 and Python is 3.10, thank you

Comment: Which Python **client library** are you using?

Comment: `from langchain.vectorstores import ElasticVectorSearch`

Comment: Also worth noting that `ElasticVectorSearch` [has been deprecated](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/vectorstores/elasticsearch#whats-new) and you should now use `ElasticsearchStore` instead

Comment: Thank you very much! but still not working, something very strange...

Comment: maybe it has something with the mapping of the index i created in ES?

Comment: Yes, you need to create an index whose mapping contains a field of type `dense_vector` as you can see in the [default mapping](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/c732d8fffd39d2b02bdc393c37d2ccdd48f7626d/libs/langchain/langchain/vectorstores/elastic_vector_search.py#L28-L34) created by langchain. It was probably the case in your previous index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an index whose mapping contains a `vector` field of type `dense_vector` as you can see in the [default mapping](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/c732d8fffd39d2b02bdc393c37d2ccdd48f7626d/libs/langchain/langchain/vectorstores/elastic_vector_search.py#L28-L34) created by langchain. It was probably the case in your previous index.

You can mimick what the langchain code does and do it like this (make sure that `dims` match the number of dimensions created by OpenAI, usually 1536):

```
mapping = {
    "properties": {
        "text": {"type": "text"},
        "vector": {"type": "dense_vector", "dims": 1536},
    }
}  
client.options(ignore_status=400).indices.create(index = os.environ["ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX_NAME"], mapping=mapping)
```

Note that [judging by the source code](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/c732d8fffd39d2b02bdc393c37d2ccdd48f7626d/libs/langchain/langchain/vectorstores/elastic_vector_search.py#L199), I'm not sure why langchain doesn't create the index if it doesn't exist.

Comment: FYI: The method "from_documents" create it already with these parameters (vector, dims...)

Comment: Then it's all good, you don't need to do it yourself.